# garden of Eden = garden of the Lord = garden of God?

Tags: genesis, ezekiel

Genesis 2:8

> And the LORD God planted a garden in **Eden**, in the east, where He placed the man He had formed.

Genesis 13:10
New International Version

> Lot looked around and saw that the whole plain of the Jordan toward Zoar was well watered, like the **garden of the LORD**, like the land of Egypt.

Ezekiel 31:8

> The cedars in the **garden of God** could not rival it, nor could the junipers equal its boughs, nor could the plane trees compare with its branches-- no tree in the garden of God could match its beauty.

Are these three gardens refer to the same one?

Answer (score 1):

**Garden of God**

The phrase "Garden of God" only occurs in a few places and in the following it is another name of "Eden"

- Eze 31:9 - made it beautiful with abundant branches, the envy of all the trees of Eden in the garden of God.
- Eze 28:13 - You were in Eden, the garden of God;
- Rev 2:7 - will give the right to eat the fruit of the tree of life that grows in the Garden of God.

Garden of the LORD

The phrase "Garden of the LORD" is also infrequent but in the following it is another name for "Eden"

- Isa 51:3 - he will make her deserts like Eden, her wastelands like the garden of the LORD

Thus, it appears that both phrases, "Garden of God" and "Garden of the LORD" are names for "Eden".